# Database table relationship design

Tags: mysql, sql, database, ms-access

I am trying to write out a database design to include the following relationships, I have tried to work them out from the top down, hierarchically, but the relationships seem to be better connected another way, I just cannot see, or express how.

(This comes from a FOUO system from work, so the names have been changed to reflect that classification, that's why the names may look odd.)

Each *Branch* 1:n *Functional Areas*,

Each *Building* 1:n *Groups*,

Each *Group* 1:n *Units*,

Each *FunctionalArea* 1:n *Checklists*,

Each *Checklist* 1:n *Items*, and

Each *Unit* 1:n *Checklists* and

This was solved by re-evaluating the relationships without concern for the size or data type they would hold. 1:n relationships were used in lieu of n:n.

Comment: Yes. If many-to-many then 'bridging' tables are required

Comment: If you are not limited to a relational database, a graph database such as Neo4j can handle this easily. If you are limited to a relational database, Strawberry's comment is your best option.

Comment: Is each functional area specific to a branch, or can it belong to more than one branch?  If it can belong to more than one branch then it is a many-to-may and you need a bridging table.  However if a Functional area belongs to a specific branch all you need is the BranchID as a Foreign Key in the Functional Areas table.  Work through each relationship answering the same question and chose the appropriate structure.

Comment: try specifying both sides of each relationship with cardinality (1 or 1-or-more). E.g. a Building contains? 1-or-more Functional Areas. A Functional Area is contained in ?1 Building. You can also look at both optionalities. Can a building have no functional area? can a functional area exist without a building.  This is a bit more precise. And you can build from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are designing a database you need to be specific about the relationships. For example you need to mention things like "A functional area can only belongs to a one branch only". These will help to determine either we are going to have 1:1 relations or 1:n or something else.

However i have come up with an answer.
[image: see the image]

Comment: This did the job for the most part, But changed the Branch 1:n Building and Branch 1:n FunctionalArea. No FUnctionalArea to Building was necessary after [Link]http://stackoverflow.com/users/4296944/andras @Andras mentioned the number being arbitray at the moment, allowed me to think about a bit more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

one simple way I've used that would handle this is to have tables for each pairing:  branch-function, building-function, building-group, group-unit, unit-checklist, checklist-item, keeping the objects and relationships separate.

It's basically tuple soup, but keeping that sorted is what a relational db is good at.  Accesses will be doing primary-key joins on multiple tables.  How large do you expect your dataset to grow?

The limits (100 checklists, etc) are policy.  Design the schema for simplicity and performance, implement policy in the application layer.

Comment: Thank you, not worrying about the numbers for now allowed me to think a bit more clearly on the relationship.